# Are there infinitely many solutions such that the digit sum of a prime power is a smaller power of the same prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, decimal-expansion, conjectures

While discussing prime powers and divisors,  I came up with the following problem.

### Examples

$\to$ prime $p=3$

- digit sum (in base ten) of $p^3=27$ is $p^2=9$, a power of $p$,.

$\to$ prime $p=7$

- digit sum of $p^4=2401$ is $p^1=7$, a power of $p$.

*We can get even crazier:*

$\to$ prime $p=5$

- digit sum of $p^{208}$ is equal to $p^4=625$.

*and so on*.

The PARI/GP code used to generate the examples is below:

`sfun(p,k,n)={for(q=2,n,if(sumdigits(p^q,10)==p^k,print(q)))}`.

### Questions

> **Main question:**
>
> Denote the digit sum (in base ten) of an integer $m$ as $s(m)$.
>
> Are there infinitely many solutions such that $$s(p^n)=p^k$$ where $p$ is a prime, and $k,n$ are positive integers?

When $p=3$, it has the nice property that $s(3^n)$ is always divisible by $3$, so the first few solutions are not very hard to find. For example, when $k=3$, we obtain $n=9,10,11,13,16,17,21$.

Some experimentation with the code reveals that the solutions get sparser as $p$ increases, as expected. But the solutions themselves are very unexpected, such as $$s(5^{4938})=5^6,\quad s(89^{898})=89^2.$$ Thus I believe in the finitude of the solutions, but I think evaluating them will be out of the question. To disprove my claim, it suffices to show that for every $p$ there is a solution, since we know that the number of primes is infinite.

Comment: Solutions for $p=3$ are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A118872 and for $p=2$ at http://oeis.org/A067499

Comment: Here's $p=5$: http://oeis.org/A067502 and $p=7$: http://oeis.org/A067504 (but why limit yourself to powers of primes?).